# Custom Gallery Shortcode using Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, shortcode

i try to work with code i find online.

In detail: http://www.rinconstrategies.io/custom-gallery-shortcode-for-wordpress.html

I use and make debug and i see problem with parse.

```
<?php 
function create_gallery_view( $atts ) {
$images = get_field('gallery_view');

$innerHTML = '';
foreach( $images as $image ) {
    $thumb = $image['sizes']['thumbnail'];
    $alt = $image['alt'];
    $caption = $image['caption'];
    $innerHTML .= "<li>
            <img src=$thumb alt=$alt />
            <p>$caption</p>
        </li>";
}

$html = <<<HTML
<ul class="gallery-view-flex">
    {$innerHTML}
</ul>
HTML;

echo $html;
}

add_shortcode('gallery_view', 'create_gallery_view');
?>
```

In my debug the line have some problem.

```
$html = <<<HTML
 <ul class="gallery-view-flex">
{$innerHTML}
 </ul>
 HTML;

  echo $html;
```

I read online heredoc have this format.
But i motivi understand why debug say about parse problem.

Someone can help me for understand?
thanks
Paolo

Comment: You'll never get an answer for this. How should anyone know about your problem? Please try to understand the nature of your problem yourself and  ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

Heredoc closing identifier MUST NOT be indent.

error

```
    $html = <<<HTML
 HTML; // space indent
```

---

correct

```
    $html = <<<HTML
HTML; // no indent
```